# Create 2 vars and comparate them with an if

Tags: bash

I have been looking on the internet but none of the "solutions" has worked. I create 2 variables with the result of a command and then I try to compare them with an *if* but it just doesn't work :(

```
#!/bin/bash

pre_result=`digest -a md5 -v $1`
md5=${pre_result:(-33)}

pre_result2=`digest -a md5 -v /respaldo/directorio`
md52=${pre_result2:(-33)}

if $md5 != $md52
then
    fecha=`date`
    `mkdir /respaldo/"$fecha"`
    `cp $1  /respaldo/"$fecha"/`
else
     echo ':('
fi
```

Thanks a lot for your attention, and sorry for the bad English ;)

Comment: If you put backticks around your `mkdir` and `cp` commands you'll get an error. Just leave them out. And where they are needed (`digest` and `date`) you should use `$()` instead (e.g. `$(date)`). It's more readable and easier to use. See [BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). Your English is very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional expressions need to be inside of brackets in bash.

So your if statement should read:

```
if [[ $md5 != $md52 ]]
then
# do stuff
fi
```

[This link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-conditional-expression/) has more details about bash conditional expressions.

Comment: Better would be to use `[[` and `]]` if writing for bash rather than POSIX sh -- among other things, that would actually remove the need to quote the left-hand side, ie. `[[ $md5 != "$md52" ]]` (and the need to quote the right-hand-side only persists to prevent it from being treated as a glob, not due to potential for string-splitting).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah I'm always unsure of whether or not to use POSIX sh.  I guess since he specified bash then it's okay.  See my edits.